# getting an attribute value by another one

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm trying to get an attribute value from a different tag.
Here's my xml file:

```
<XMI xmi.version='1.2' timestamp='Fri Apr 24 12:24:29 WAT 2015' xmlns:UML='omg.org/UML/1.4'>
<XMI.header>
    <XMI.documentation>
        <XMI.exporter>MagicDraw UML</XMI.exporter>
        <XMI.exporterVersion>9.0</XMI.exporterVersion>
    </XMI.documentation>
    <XMI.metamodel xmi.name='UML' xmi.version='1.4'/>
</XMI.header>
<XMI.content>
    <UML:Model xmi.id='eee_1045467100313_135436_1' name='Data'>
        <UML:Namespace.ownedElement>
            <UML:Package xmi.id='_9_0_1abc0480_1360417290093_794953_110' name='hr'>
                                <UML:Namespace.ownedElement>
                                    <UML:Class xmi.id='_9_0_1abc0480_1360417356156_809319_114' name='Employee'>
                                        <UML:ModelElement.stereotype>
                                            <UML:Stereotype href='newModel.xml|egiva_1022741650486_759581_123'>
                                                <XMI.extension xmi.extender='MagicDraw UML 9.0' xmi.extenderID='MagicDraw UML 9.0'>
                                                    <referentPath xmi.value='Data types::entity'/>
                                                </XMI.extension>
                                            </UML:Stereotype>
                                        </UML:ModelElement.stereotype>
                                        <UML:Namespace.ownedElement>
                                            <UML:Abstraction xmi.id='_9_0_1abc0480_1360417353312_416353_113' client='_9_0_1abc0480_1360417356156_809319_114'>
                                                <UML:ModelElement.stereotype>
                                                    <UML:Stereotype href='newModel.xml|_9_0_897027e_1105630590734_613299_511'>
                                                        <XMI.extension xmi.extender='MagicDraw UML 9.0' xmi.extenderID='MagicDraw UML 9.0'>
                                                            <referentPath xmi.value='Data types::realize'/>
                                                        </XMI.extension>
                                                    </UML:Stereotype>
                                                </UML:ModelElement.stereotype>
                                                <UML:Dependency.supplier>
                                                    <UML:ModelElement href='newModel.xml|osama_1059572400642_541580_122'>
                                                        <XMI.extension xmi.extender='MagicDraw UML 9.0' xmi.extenderID='MagicDraw UML 9.0'>
                                                            <referentPath xmi.value='com::new::arch::basicStruct::data::AbstractValue'/>
                                                        </XMI.extension>
                                                    </UML:ModelElement>
                                                </UML:Dependency.supplier>
                                            </UML:Abstraction>
                                        </UML:Namespace.ownedElement>
                                        <UML:Classifier.feature>
                                            <UML:Attribute xmi.id='_9_0_1abc0480_1360417405078_72412_147' name='identifier'>
                                                <UML:StructuralFeature.multiplicity>
                                                    <UML:Multiplicity xmi.id='_9_0_1abc0480_1360417783468_448855_210'>
                                                        <UML:Multiplicity.range>
                                                            <UML:MultiplicityRange xmi.id='_9_0_1abc0480_1360417783468_577212_211' lower='1' upper='1'/>
                                                        </UML:Multiplicity.range>
                                                    </UML:Multiplicity>
                                                </UML:StructuralFeature.multiplicity>
                                                <UML:ModelElement.stereotype>
                                                    <UML:Stereotype href='newModel.xml|_5f701fc_1096291047273_745359_1547'>
                                                        <XMI.extension xmi.extender='MagicDraw UML 9.0' xmi.extenderID='MagicDraw UML 9.0'>
                                                            <referentPath xmi.value='Data types::code'/>
                                                        </XMI.extension>
                                                    </UML:Stereotype>
                                                    <UML:Stereotype href='newModel.xml|_5f701fc_1096282286643_472107_1342'>
                                                        <XMI.extension xmi.extender='MagicDraw UML 9.0' xmi.extenderID='MagicDraw UML 9.0'>
                                                            <referentPath xmi.value='Data types::sequence'/>
                                                        </XMI.extension>
                                                    </UML:Stereotype>
                                                </UML:ModelElement.stereotype>
                                                <UML:StructuralFeature.type>
                                                    <UML:Classifier href='newModel.xml|ahmad_1057828584656_303948_819'>
                                                        <XMI.extension xmi.extender='MagicDraw UML 9.0' xmi.extenderID='MagicDraw UML 9.0'>
                                                            <referentPath xmi.value='com::new::arch::basicStruct::data::LongValue'/>
                                                        </XMI.extension>
                                                    </UML:Classifier>
                                                </UML:StructuralFeature.type>
                                            </UML:Attribute>
                                            <UML:Attribute xmi.id='_9_0_1abc0480_1360417733453_835499_209' name='nationalNumber'>
                                                <UML:StructuralFeature.multiplicity>
                                                    <UML:Multiplicity xmi.id='_9_0_1abc0480_1360417783468_891620_212'>
                                                        <UML:Multiplicity.range>
                                                            <UML:MultiplicityRange xmi.id='_9_0_1abc0480_1360417783468_892394_213' lower='1' upper='1'/>
                                                        </UML:Multiplicity.range>
                                                    </UML:Multiplicity>
                                                </UML:StructuralFeature.multiplicity>
                                                <UML:ModelElement.stereotype>
                                                    <UML:Stereotype href='newModel.xml|_5f701fc_1096291083287_539898_1561'>
                                                        <XMI.extension xmi.extender='MagicDraw UML 9.0' xmi.extenderID='MagicDraw UML 9.0'>
                                                            <referentPath xmi.value='Data types::unique'/>
                                                        </XMI.extension>
                                                    </UML:Stereotype>
                                                </UML:ModelElement.stereotype>
                                                <UML:StructuralFeature.type>
                                                    <UML:Classifier href='newModel.xml|ahmad_1057828584656_303948_819'>
                                                        <XMI.extension xmi.extender='MagicDraw UML 9.0' xmi.extenderID='MagicDraw UML 9.0'>
                                                            <referentPath xmi.value='com::new::arch::basicStruct::data::LongValue'/>
                                                        </XMI.extension>
                                                    </UML:Classifier>
                                                </UML:StructuralFeature.type>
                                            </UML:Attribute>
                                            <UML:Attribute xmi.id='_9_0_1abc0480_1360417420906_228687_149' name='firstName'>
                                                <UML:StructuralFeature.multiplicity>
                                                    <UML:Multiplicity xmi.id='_9_0_1abc0480_1360417783468_425799_214'>
                                                        <UML:Multiplicity.range>
                                                            <UML:MultiplicityRange xmi.id='_9_0_1abc0480_1360417783468_373524_215' lower='1' upper='1'/>
                                                        </UML:Multiplicity.range>
                                                    </UML:Multiplicity>
                                                </UML:StructuralFeature.multiplicity>
                                                <UML:StructuralFeature.type>
                                                    <UML:Classifier href='newModel.xml|ahmad_1057828584656_67517_836'>
                                                        <XMI.extension xmi.extender='MagicDraw UML 9.0' xmi.extenderID='MagicDraw UML 9.0'>
                                                            <referentPath xmi.value='com::new::arch::basicStruct::data::StringValue'/>
                                                        </XMI.extension>
                                                    </UML:Classifier>
                                                </UML:StructuralFeature.type>
                                            </UML:Attribute>
                                            <UML:Attribute xmi.id='_9_0_1abc0480_1360417434156_213690_151' name='lastName'>
                                                <UML:StructuralFeature.multiplicity>
                                                    <UML:Multiplicity xmi.id='_9_0_1abc0480_1360417783468_611745_216'>
                                                        <UML:Multiplicity.range>
                                                            <UML:MultiplicityRange xmi.id='_9_0_1abc0480_1360417783468_180814_217' lower='1' upper='1'/>
                                                        </UML:Multiplicity.range>
                                                    </UML:Multiplicity>
                                                </UML:StructuralFeature.multiplicity>
                                                <UML:StructuralFeature.type>
                                                    <UML:Classifier href='newModel.xml|ahmad_1057828584656_67517_836'>
                                                        <XMI.extension xmi.extender='MagicDraw UML 9.0' xmi.extenderID='MagicDraw UML 9.0'>
                                                            <referentPath xmi.value='com::new::arch::basicStruct::data::StringValue'/>
                                                        </XMI.extension>
                                                    </UML:Classifier>
                                                </UML:StructuralFeature.type>
                                            </UML:Attribute>
                                            <UML:Attribute xmi.id='_9_0_1abc0480_1360417449984_748333_153' name='birthDate'>
                                                <UML:StructuralFeature.multiplicity>
                                                    <UML:Multiplicity xmi.id='_9_0_1abc0480_1360417783468_837478_218'>
                                                        <UML:Multiplicity.range>
                                                            <UML:MultiplicityRange xmi.id='_9_0_1abc0480_1360417783468_515637_219' lower='1' upper='1'/>
                                                        </UML:Multiplicity.range>
                                                    </UML:Multiplicity>
                                                </UML:StructuralFeature.multiplicity>
                                                <UML:StructuralFeature.type>
                                                    <UML:Classifier href='newModel.xml|5f701fc_1081944857059_464638_0'>
                                                        <XMI.extension xmi.extender='MagicDraw UML 9.0' xmi.extenderID='MagicDraw UML 9.0'>
                                                            <referentPath xmi.value='com::new::arch::basicStruct::data::BusinessDate'/>
                                                        </XMI.extension>
                                                    </UML:Classifier>
                                                </UML:StructuralFeature.type>
                                            </UML:Attribute>
                                            <UML:Attribute xmi.id='_9_0_1abc0480_1360417653468_896023_199' name='age'>
                                                <UML:StructuralFeature.multiplicity>
                                                    <UML:Multiplicity xmi.id='_9_0_1abc0480_1360417783468_747933_220'>
                                                        <UML:Multiplicity.range>
                                                            <UML:MultiplicityRange xmi.id='_9_0_1abc0480_1360417783468_274122_221' lower='1' upper='1'/>
                                                        </UML:Multiplicity.range>
                                                    </UML:Multiplicity>
                                                </UML:StructuralFeature.multiplicity>
                                                <UML:StructuralFeature.type>
                                                    <UML:Classifier href='newModel.xml|ahmad_1057828584656_716005_817'>
                                                        <XMI.extension xmi.extender='MagicDraw UML 9.0' xmi.extenderID='MagicDraw UML 9.0'>
                                                            <referentPath xmi.value='com::new::arch::basicStruct::data::IntegerValue'/>
                                                        </XMI.extension>
                                                    </UML:Classifier>
                                                </UML:StructuralFeature.type>
                                            </UML:Attribute>
                                            <UML:Attribute xmi.id='_9_0_1abc0480_1360417667046_866560_201' name='address'>
                                                <UML:StructuralFeature.multiplicity>
                                                    <UML:Multiplicity xmi.id='_9_0_1abc0480_1360417783468_142919_222'>
                                                        <UML:Multiplicity.range>
                                                            <UML:MultiplicityRange xmi.id='_9_0_1abc0480_1360417783468_940840_223' lower='1' upper='1'/>
                                                        </UML:Multiplicity.range>
                                                    </UML:Multiplicity>
                                                </UML:StructuralFeature.multiplicity>
                                                <UML:StructuralFeature.type>
                                                    <UML:Classifier href='newModel.xml|osama_1057833941718_811415_136'>
                                                        <XMI.extension xmi.extender='MagicDraw UML 9.0' xmi.extenderID='MagicDraw UML 9.0'>
                                                            <referentPath xmi.value='com::new::arch::basicStruct::data::TextValue'/>
                                                        </XMI.extension>
                                                    </UML:Classifier>
                                                </UML:StructuralFeature.type>
                                            </UML:Attribute>
                                            <UML:Attribute xmi.id='_9_0_1abc0480_1360417684531_808413_203' name='phoneNumber'>
                                                <UML:StructuralFeature.multiplicity>
                                                    <UML:Multiplicity xmi.id='_9_0_1abc0480_1360418132359_292342_291'>
                                                        <UML:Multiplicity.range>
                                                            <UML:MultiplicityRange xmi.id='_9_0_1abc0480_1360418132359_144507_292' lower='1' upper='1'/>
                                                        </UML:Multiplicity.range>
                                                    </UML:Multiplicity>
                                                </UML:StructuralFeature.multiplicity>
                                                <UML:StructuralFeature.type>
                                                    <UML:Classifier href='newModel.xml|ahmad_1057828584656_67517_836'>
                                                        <XMI.extension xmi.extender='MagicDraw UML 9.0' xmi.extenderID='MagicDraw UML 9.0'>
                                                            <referentPath xmi.value='com::new::arch::basicStruct::data::StringValue'/>
                                                        </XMI.extension>
                                                    </UML:Classifier>
                                                </UML:StructuralFeature.type>
                                            </UML:Attribute>
                                            <UML:Attribute xmi.id='_9_0_1abc0480_1360417699265_17119_205' name='contractStartDate'>
                                                <UML:StructuralFeature.multiplicity>
                                                    <UML:Multiplicity xmi.id='_9_0_1abc0480_1360417783468_343557_226'>
                                                        <UML:Multiplicity.range>
                                                            <UML:MultiplicityRange xmi.id='_9_0_1abc0480_1360417783468_361878_227' lower='1' upper='1'/>
                                                        </UML:Multiplicity.range>
                                                    </UML:Multiplicity>
                                                </UML:StructuralFeature.multiplicity>
                                                <UML:StructuralFeature.type>
                                                    <UML:Classifier href='newModel.xml|5f701fc_1081944857059_464638_0'>
                                                        <XMI.extension xmi.extender='MagicDraw UML 9.0' xmi.extenderID='MagicDraw UML 9.0'>
                                                            <referentPath xmi.value='com::new::arch::basicStruct::data::BusinessDate'/>
                                                        </XMI.extension>
                                                    </UML:Classifier>
                                                </UML:StructuralFeature.type>
                                            </UML:Attribute>
                                            <UML:Attribute xmi.id='_9_0_1abc0480_1360417718562_213156_207' name='contractEndDate'>
                                                <UML:StructuralFeature.multiplicity>
                                                    <UML:Multiplicity xmi.id='_9_0_1abc0480_1360417783468_929078_228'>
                                                        <UML:Multiplicity.range>
                                                            <UML:MultiplicityRange xmi.id='_9_0_1abc0480_1360417783468_350602_229' lower='0' upper='1'/>
                                                        </UML:Multiplicity.range>
                                                    </UML:Multiplicity>
                                                </UML:StructuralFeature.multiplicity>
                                                <UML:StructuralFeature.type>
                                                    <UML:Classifier href='newModel.xml|5f701fc_1081944857059_464638_0'>
                                                        <XMI.extension xmi.extender='MagicDraw UML 9.0' xmi.extenderID='MagicDraw UML 9.0'>
                                                            <referentPath xmi.value='com::arch::basicStruct::data::BusinessDate'/>
                                                        </XMI.extension>
                                                    </UML:Classifier>
                                                </UML:StructuralFeature.type>
                                            </UML:Attribute>
                                            <UML:Attribute xmi.id='_9_0_1abc0480_1360417795250_360778_246' name='civilState' type='_9_0_1abc0480_1360417555656_961843_176'>
                                                <UML:StructuralFeature.multiplicity>
                                                    <UML:Multiplicity xmi.id='_9_0_1abc0480_1360418132359_514503_293'>
                                                        <UML:Multiplicity.range>
                                                            <UML:MultiplicityRange xmi.id='_9_0_1abc0480_1360418132359_191202_294' lower='1' upper='1'/>
                                                        </UML:Multiplicity.range>
                                                    </UML:Multiplicity>
                                                </UML:StructuralFeature.multiplicity>
                                            </UML:Attribute>
                                            <UML:Attribute xmi.id='_9_0_1abc0480_1360417815687_976484_248' name='numberOfChildren'>
                                                <UML:StructuralFeature.multiplicity>
                                                    <UML:Multiplicity xmi.id='_9_0_1abc0480_1360418132359_201182_295'>
                                                        <UML:Multiplicity.range>
                                                            <UML:MultiplicityRange xmi.id='_9_0_1abc0480_1360418132359_799315_296' lower='0' upper='1'/>
                                                        </UML:Multiplicity.range>
                                                    </UML:Multiplicity>
                                                </UML:StructuralFeature.multiplicity>
                                                <UML:StructuralFeature.type>
                                                    <UML:Classifier >
                                                        <XMI.extension xmi.extender='MagicDraw UML 9.0' xmi.extenderID='MagicDraw UML 9.0'>
                                                            <referentPath xmi.value='com::new::arch::basicStruct::data::IntegerValue'/>
                                                        </XMI.extension>
                                                    </UML:Classifier>
                                                </UML:StructuralFeature.type>
                                            </UML:Attribute>
                                            <UML:Attribute xmi.id='_9_0_1abc0480_1360417865968_440560_250' name='salary'>
                                                <UML:StructuralFeature.multiplicity>
                                                    <UML:Multiplicity xmi.id='_9_0_1abc0480_1360418132359_655101_297'>
                                                        <UML:Multiplicity.range>
                                                            <UML:MultiplicityRange xmi.id='_9_0_1abc0480_1360418132359_229798_298' lower='1' upper='1'/>
                                                        </UML:Multiplicity.range>
                                                    </UML:Multiplicity>
                                                </UML:StructuralFeature.multiplicity>
                                                <UML:StructuralFeature.type>
                                                    <UML:Classifier >
                                                        <XMI.extension xmi.extender='MagicDraw UML 9.0' xmi.extenderID='MagicDraw UML 9.0'>
                                                            <referentPath xmi.value='com::new::arch::basicStruct::data::DoubleValue'/>
                                                        </XMI.extension>
                                                    </UML:Classifier>
                                                </UML:StructuralFeature.type>
                                            </UML:Attribute>
                                        </UML:Classifier.feature>
                                    </UML:Class>
                                    <UML:Association xmi.id='_9_0_1abc0480_1360418146656_245894_318'>
                                        <UML:Association.connection>
                                            <UML:AssociationEnd xmi.id='_9_0_1abc0480_1360418146656_962005_316' isNavigable='true' aggregation='aggregate' participant='_9_0_1abc0480_1360417356156_809319_114'>
                                                <UML:AssociationEnd.multiplicity>
                                                    <UML:Multiplicity xmi.id='_9_0_1abc0480_1360418222968_828268_417'>
                                                        <UML:Multiplicity.range>
                                                            <UML:MultiplicityRange xmi.id='_9_0_1abc0480_1360418222968_333793_418' lower='0' upper='-1'/>
                                                        </UML:Multiplicity.range>
                                                    </UML:Multiplicity>
                                                </UML:AssociationEnd.multiplicity>
                                            </UML:AssociationEnd>
                                            <UML:AssociationEnd xmi.id='_9_0_1abc0480_1360418146656_839833_317' isNavigable='true' participant='_9_0_1abc0480_1360417892796_581831_252'>
                                                <UML:AssociationEnd.multiplicity>
                                                    <UML:Multiplicity xmi.id='_9_0_1abc0480_1360418222968_561784_419'>
                                                        <UML:Multiplicity.range>
                                                            <UML:MultiplicityRange xmi.id='_9_0_1abc0480_1360418222968_684290_420' lower='1' upper='1'/>
                                                        </UML:Multiplicity.range>
                                                    </UML:Multiplicity>
                                                </UML:AssociationEnd.multiplicity>
                                            </UML:AssociationEnd>
                                        </UML:Association.connection>
                                    </UML:Association
                                </UML:Namespace.ownedElement>
            </UML:Package>
        </UML:Namespace.ownedElement>
    </UML:Model>
   </XMI.content>
 </XMI>
```

I want to extract the value of the attribute name of the tag `<UML:Class>` from the attribute participant of the `<UML:Association>`.
Here what I did in the XSLT file :

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:UML='omg.org/UML/1.4' xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI"
xmlns:uml="http://www.eclipse.org/uml2/3.0.0/UML" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ecore="http://www.eclipse.org/emf/2002/Ecore"
xmlns:palmyraUMLprofile="http:///schemas/palmyraUMLprofile/_oXvaUNuaEeCgfpbtt2dTfQ/5"
xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" version="1.0">
<xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
<xsl:template match="UML:Class">
    <packagedElement>
        <xsl:attribute name="xmi:type">uml:Class</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="xmi:id">
            <xsl:value-of select="@xmi.id" />
          </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="name">
            <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
          </xsl:attribute>
        <generalization>
            <xsl:attribute name="xmi:id">
              <xsl:value-of select="generate-id()" />
            </xsl:attribute>
            <general xmi:type="uml:Class" />
        </generalization>
        <xsl:for-each select="//UML:Association/UML:Association.connection/UML:AssociationEnd/@aggregation='composite'">

        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:for-each select="UML:Classifier.feature/UML:Attribute">
            <ownedAttribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="xmi:id">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="@xmi.id" />
                                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="name">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
                                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="isUnique">false</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:variable name="hreff">
                    <xsl:call-template name="replace_palmyra">
                        <xsl:with-param name="text"
                            select="UML:StructuralFeature.type/UML:Classifier/@href" />
                        <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="'PalmyraModel.xml|'" />
                        <xsl:with-param name="by"
                            select="'platform:/plugin/PalmyraUmlProfile/PalmyraModel/PalmyraModel.uml#'" />
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:variable>
                <type xmi:type="uml:Class" href="{$hreff}" />

                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when
                        test="UML:StructuralFeature.multiplicity/UML:Multiplicity/UML:Multiplicity.range/UML:MultiplicityRange/@lower !=''">
                        <lowerValue xmi:type="uml:LiteralInteger" xmi:id="{generate-id()}"
                            value="{UML:StructuralFeature.multiplicity/UML:Multiplicity/UML:Multiplicity.range/UML:MultiplicityRange/@lower}" />
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <lowerValue xmi:type="uml:LiteralInteger" xmi:id="{generate-id()}" />
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </ownedAttribute>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </packagedElement>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="UML:Association">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="UML:Association.connection/UML:AssociationEnd/@aggregation='composite'">
            <packagedElement>
                <xsl:attribute name="xmi:type">uml:Association</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="xmi:id">
            <xsl:value-of select="@xmi.id" />
          </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="name">compositon</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:variable name="member1" select="concat(generate-id(),'a1')" />
                <xsl:variable name="member2" select="concat(generate-id(),'a2')" />

                <xsl:attribute name="memberEnd">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat($member1,' ',$member2)" />
          </xsl:attribute>
                <ownedEnd>
                    <xsl:attribute name="xmi:id">
            <xsl:value-of select="@xmi.id" />
          </xsl:attribute>
                    <!--<xsl:variable name="name-association1"> <xsl:value-of select="UML:Association.connection/UML:AssociationEnd[1]/@participant" 
                        /> <xsl:value-of select="*/UML:Class[@id='UML:Association.connection/UML:AssociationEnd[1]/@participant']/@name"/> 
                        </xsl:variable> -->
                    <xsl:attribute name="name">
            <xsl:value-of select="hello" />
          </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="type">
            <xsl:value-of select="@xmi.id" />
          </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="isUnique">false</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="name">
            <xsl:value-of select="association" />
          </xsl:attribute>
                    <upperValue xmi:type="uml:LiteralUnlimitedNatural"
                        xmi:id="{concat(generate-id(),'id1')}"
                        value="{UML:Association.connection/UML:AssociationEnd/UML:AssociationEnd.multiplicity/UML:Multiplicity/UML:Multiplicity.range/UML:MultiplicityRange/@upper}" />
                    <lowerValue xmi:type="uml:LiteralInteger" xmi:id="{concat(generate-id(),'id2')}"
                        value="{UML:Association.connection/UML:AssociationEnd/UML:AssociationEnd.multiplicity/UML:Multiplicity/UML:Multiplicity.range/UML:MultiplicityRange/@lower}" />
                </ownedEnd>
            </packagedElement>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when
            test="UML:Association.connection/UML:AssociationEnd/@aggregation='aggregate'">
            <packagedElement>
                <xsl:attribute name="xmi:type">uml:Association</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="xmi:id">
            <xsl:value-of select="@xmi.id" />
          </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="name">aggregation</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:variable name="member1" select="concat(generate-id(),'a1')" />
                <xsl:variable name="member2" select="concat(generate-id(),'a2')" />
                <xsl:variable name="id1"
                    select="UML:Association.connection/UML:AssociationEnd[1]/@participant" />
                <xsl:variable name="id2"
                    select="UML:Association.connection/UML:AssociationEnd[2]/@participant" />
                <xsl:attribute name="memberEnd">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat($member1,' ',$member2)" />
          </xsl:attribute>
                <ownedEnd>
                    <xsl:attribute name="xmi:id">
            <xsl:value-of select="$member1" />
          </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="name">
            <xsl:value-ofselect="//UML:Class[@xmi.id='UML:Association.connection/UML:AssociationEnd/@participant']/@name" />
</xsl:attribute>" />
          </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="type">
            <xsl:value-of
                        select="UML:Association.connection/UML:AssociationEnd[1]/@participant" />
          </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="isUnique">false</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="association">
            <xsl:value-of select="@xmi.id" />
          </xsl:attribute>
                    <upperValue xmi:type="uml:LiteralUnlimitedNatural"
                        xmi:id="{generate-id()}"
                        value="{UML:Association.connection/UML:AssociationEnd[1]/UML:AssociationEnd.multiplicity/UML:Multiplicity/UML:Multiplicity.range/UML:MultiplicityRange/@upper}" />
                    <lowerValue xmi:type="uml:LiteralInteger" xmi:id="{generate-id()}"
                        value="{UML:Association.connection/UML:AssociationEnd[1]/UML:AssociationEnd.multiplicity/UML:Multiplicity/UML:Multiplicity.range/UML:MultiplicityRange/@lower}" />
                </ownedEnd>
                <ownedEnd>
                    <xsl:attribute name="xmi:id">
            <xsl:value-of select="$member2" />
          </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="name">
            <xsl:value-of select="hello" />
          </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="type">
            <xsl:value-of
                        select="UML:Association.connection/UML:AssociationEnd[2]/@participant" />
          </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="isUnique">false</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="association">
            <xsl:value-of select="@xmi.id" />
          </xsl:attribute>
                    <upperValue xmi:type="uml:LiteralUnlimitedNatural"
                        xmi:id="{generate-id()}"
                        value="{UML:Association.connection/UML:AssociationEnd[2]/UML:AssociationEnd.multiplicity/UML:Multiplicity/UML:Multiplicity.range/UML:MultiplicityRange/@upper}" />
                    <lowerValue xmi:type="uml:LiteralInteger" xmi:id="{generate-id()}"
                        value="{UML:Association.connection/UML:AssociationEnd[2]/UML:AssociationEnd.multiplicity/UML:Multiplicity/UML:Multiplicity.range/UML:MultiplicityRange/@lower}" />
                </ownedEnd>
            </packagedElement>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when
            test="UML:Association.connection/UML:AssociationEnd[not(@aggregation)]">
            <packagedElement>
                <xsl:attribute name="xmi:type">association</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="xmi:id">
            <xsl:value-of select="@xmi.id" />
          </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="name">
            <xsl:value-of select="association" />
          </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:variable name="member1" select="concat(generate-id(),'a1')" />
                <xsl:variable name="member2" select="concat(generate-id(),'a2')" />

                <xsl:attribute name="memberEnd">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat($member1,' ',$member2)" />
                                </xsl:attribute>
                <ownedEnd>
                    <xsl:attribute name="xmi:id">
            <xsl:value-of select="@xmi.id" />
          </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="name">
            <xsl:value-of select="Hello" />
          </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="type">
            <xsl:value-of select="@xmi.id" />
          </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="isUnique">false</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="association">
            <xsl:value-of select="@xmi.id" />
          </xsl:attribute>
                    <upperValue xmi:type="uml:LiteralUnlimitedNatural"
                        xmi:id="{generate-id()}"
                        value="{UML:Association.connection/UML:AssociationEnd[1]/UML:AssociationEnd.multiplicity/UML:Multiplicity/UML:Multiplicity.range/UML:MultiplicityRange/@upper}" />
                    <lowerValue xmi:type="uml:LiteralInteger" xmi:id="{generate-id()}"
                        value="{UML:Association.connection/UML:AssociationEnd[1]/UML:AssociationEnd.multiplicity/UML:Multiplicity/UML:Multiplicity.range/UML:MultiplicityRange/@lower}" />
                </ownedEnd>
                <ownedEnd>
                    <xsl:attribute name="xmi:id">
            <xsl:value-of select="@xmi.id" />
          </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="name">

            <xsl:value-of select="UML:Class[@id='']" />
          </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="type">
            <xsl:value-of select="@xmi.id" />
          </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="isUnique">false</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="association">
            <xsl:value-of select="@xmi.id" />
          </xsl:attribute>
                    <upperValue xmi:type="uml:LiteralUnlimitedNatural"
                        xmi:id="{generate-id()}"
                        value="{UML:Association.connection/UML:AssociationEnd[2]/UML:AssociationEnd.multiplicity/UML:Multiplicity/UML:Multiplicity.range/UML:MultiplicityRange/@upper}" />
                    <lowerValue xmi:type="uml:LiteralInteger" xmi:id="{generate-id()}"
                        value="{UML:Association.connection/UML:AssociationEnd[2]/UML:AssociationEnd.multiplicity/UML:Multiplicity/UML:Multiplicity.range/UML:MultiplicityRange/@lower}" />
                </ownedEnd>
            </packagedElement>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: "*Here what I did in the XSLT file*" Please post a complete XSLT so that we can reproduce the issue. I believe this is the second time I am asking.

Comment: As you can see in the XSLT file I have the attribute name that must have the same value as the attribute name in the tag UML:Class so here's what I did : 
`<xsl:attribute name="name">
            <xsl:value-ofselect="//UML:Class[@xmi.id='UML:Association.connection/UML:AssociationEnd/@participant']/@name" />
</xsl:attribute>`

Comment: "*As you can see in the XSLT file..*" I cannot see anything in the XSLT file. "A complete XSLT" does NOT mean you should dump your entire file here and expect us to find the issue.  It means we should be able to copy the file and run it without adding anything to it. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you declare this `<xsl:key>` at root level of your stylesheet:

```
<xsl:key name="UMLClasses" match="UML:Class" use="@xmi.id" />
```

then you can retrieve the class name (`UML:Class/@name`) thanks to the following instruction:

```
 <xsl:value-of select="key('UMLClasses', UML:Association.connection/UML:AssociationEnd/@participant)/@name" />
```

For example, this is what I get as output:

```
<ownedEnd xmi:id="d1e155a1"
             name="Employee"
             type="_9_0_1abc0480_1360417356156_809319_114"
             isUnique="false"
             association="_9_0_1abc0480_1360418146656_245894_318">
      <upperValue xmi:type="uml:LiteralUnlimitedNatural" xmi:id="d1e155" value="-1"/>
      <lowerValue xmi:type="uml:LiteralInteger" xmi:id="d1e155" value="0"/>
   </ownedEnd>
```

However, there might be an issue because `UML:Association.connection/UML:AssociationEnd` may retrieve several nodes (`<Association.connection>` can have more than one `<AssociationEnd>`). If the first *AssociationEnd* is always the right one, it's all good for you. If not, you might have to perform the appropriate selection according to your requirements.